# Overiding functions.php with child-theme

Tags: child-theme

I've been searching for a proper solution to override functions and hooks in my parent theme's functions.php.
My parent theme has:

```
    define('TS_INC', TEMPLATEPATH .'/inc');
    require_once( TS_INC .'/file1.php');
    require_once( TS_INC .'/file2.php');
```

I want to have in my child theme an /inc folder with file2.php changed according to my needs.
This means that I want every call to file1.php to reach the parent theme /inc folder and calls to file2.php to go to my child/inc folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a parent theme, it is a standalone theme. Contact the theme author to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

You can only override functions in a Parent Theme if the Parent Theme makes functions **pluggable** (by wrapping them in an `if ( ! function_exists( 'function_name' ) )` conditional), or if the output of a function is passed through a **filter** (e.g. `return apply_filters( $filter_name, $function_output );`

1. **Pluggable functions**: in the Child Theme's `functions.php` file, simply *define a function with the same name* as the pluggable function you want to override. This is often the case with, for example, a Theme's setup function, e.g. `twentyeleven_setup()`.
2. **Filterable functions**: in the Child Theme's `functions.php` file, define a callback, and then call `add_filter( $filter_name, $callback );`

If the Parent Theme doesn't provide either of these two methods, then the Parent Theme's functions cannot be overridden in a Child Theme.

#### Edit

Just for kicks and grins, since [WordPress loads the Child Theme's `functions.php` file immediately before the Parent Theme's `functions.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php), try adding the following to your Child Theme's functions.php:

```
<?php
define( 'TS_INC', get_stylesheet_directory() .'/inc' );
?>
```

It's worth a shot, anyway.

Comment: I think these are not relevant in my case, as my parent functions.php has a "define" which I can't see how to override the way you proposed.

Comment: Please see the 3 line code bit I put in my question - it defines a TS_INC to shortcut to the /inc folder.

Comment: Actually, they *are* relevant. In PHP, [the defined value of a constant can't be changed during execution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php), so you can't simply redefine the include path. Thus, you're left with overriding the functions *in the included files*.

Comment: OK - discussion concluded on that.
Is there a way for to send it first looking in my child theme for the include and then back to the parent theme if that certain file is not available?

Comment: See updated answer. It *might* work. :)

Comment: Thanks Chip - it solves the problem in a different way.
By defining it in the child's functions.php, I now have the TS_INC defined to read from my child theme only. This means that I have to put all the parent's files from its /inc folder in the child's /inc, even if they were not changed.
This is fair enough as a solution and as a good lesson for children themes.
Thank you!

Comment: Great! If this answer solved your problem, be sure to click the checkmark beneath the question's up/down voting buttons. And welcome to WPSE!